# is there a way i can check a newly recorded data in my dabatabase in my VB.net?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Consider the following piece of code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

     If TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(0).Item(0) And TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(0).Item(1) Then
         Me.Hide()
         Form2.Show()
     Else
         Label3.Text = "invalid login"
     End If

     For a As Integer = 1 To 10
         If TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(a).Item(0) And TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(a).Item(1) Then
             Me.Hide()
             Form2.Show()
         Else
             Label3.Text = "invalid login"
         End If
     Next

 End Sub
```

This code produces an error stating :

> there is no row on position 'whatever'

I understand that the row its looking for is **yet** to be created after I register an account. My for loop strategy only works if there is already data inside the database (therefore that row is already existing), and there will be no error like my code above. But what if I want a newly added data to be checked? I did a series of work around and the best that I did was register first, quit the program, refresh my database, restart the program and login with the new recorded data.

Comment: Why are you using loop for 1 to 10 ? Just run the loop for required length. In this case, that will be **ds.Tables("outputs").Rows.count - 1**

Comment: thank u..i didnt know it can be used as a limiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check table row count first by this way：

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ds.Tables("outputs").Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Label3.Text = "invalid login"
    Else    
        For a As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("outputs").Rows.Count -1 
            If TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(a).Item(0) AndAlso TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("outputs").Rows(a).Item(1) Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
                Exit For
            Else
                Label3.Text = "invalid login"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks...i have no idea whatsoever that you can put the ds.tables as a limiter.